# Redirect request to index?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the react project, there are two index files; let's say index1.html and index2.html I have to redirect the request coming to index1 from another website to index2 and set some global variable if the website request came to index1. I totally have no idea how to solve this I don't have permission to change back-end code.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a cookie on the front end too. See [react-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie). And you get the referrer from [document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer).

Of course, usual caveats with cookies and referrers apply:

- Users may have configured their browser to not share referrer across origins, for privacy reasons.
- Users may spoof the cookie (so don't use this for anything security related). There exist a concept called "signed cookies" (see [cookie-parser middleware of express](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-parser.html)), but those require a server to sign them, and since you have no control of back end code, this is not for you.
- Users may spoof the referrer (so don't use this for anything security related)